# how to set Stored procedure with IN parameter so that it sees empty ('') as command to select all values

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find_stock_order`(
    in_product_name varchar(45),
    in_date DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT * from stock_order_view
    where product_name=in_product_name and DateTime_order=in_date;
END
```

It works when I write in values for each of these 2 parameters. However, it doesn't work when I want to find all orders by ONLY their product_name and NOT by their order dates. I don't write anything to in_date parameter (hoping that it will see it as select ANY date) but it shows an error.

EXAMPLE

I have table

| product_name | DateTime_order |
| --- | --- |
| Cola | 2022-01-01 |
| Burger | 2022-12-10 |
| Burger | 2022-06-10 |

My parameters:

1. in_product_name -  Burger
2. in_date - (I don't write anything, so it automatically sees as '')

As a result I want to see:

| product_name | DateTime_order |
| --- | --- |
| Burger | 2022-12-10 |
| Burger | 2022-06-10 |

But it shows an error as I need to type in parameter anything with DATE format

Comment: Use `WHERE (column = in_value OR in_value IS NULL)`. Provide NULL as a value when you do not want to use a filter by according column.

Comment: it doesn't work. As outcome I want to get all selected products, so it doesn't set filter on Date (including NULL)

Comment: It sounds like you think an empty string (`''`) and NULL are the same value. This is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE (column = in_value OR in_value IS NULL)` for optional columns, as suggested by @akina in the comments :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find_stock_order`(
    in_product_name varchar(45),
    in_date DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT * from stock_order_view
    where product_name=in_product_name and (DateTime_order = in_date OR in_date IS NULL);
END
```

In case you don't want to filter by DateTime_order :

```
call find_stock_order('Burger', NULL);
```

Result :

```
product_name|DateTime_order|
------------+--------------+
Burger      |    2022-12-10|
Burger      |    2022-06-10|
```

Comment: how should I change your code if I (for example) don't have option to write NULL in 'call find_stock_order('Burger', NULL);'?  I have only option to write something in appeared window with parameters that will automatically transform as call find_stock_order('Burger', NULL)